# mixing led_display and stepper_motor in emu8086

Tags: x86, x86-16

This is program in emu8086, working with stepper_motor.exe and led_display.exe.

The purpose of this program is:

When I enter number 1 in the screen, the steppet motor rotate clockwise and this increase the amount of led and when I enter 2 stepper motor rotate counter clockwise and this decrease the amount of led.

```
 mov ax, 0

mov [00000h],ax


c dw 4 
r macro data

; this is an example of out instruction.
; it writes values to virtual i/o port
; that controls the stepper-motor.
; c:\emu8086\devices\stepper_motor.exe is on port 7


steps_before_direction_change = 8h
jmp start


start:
mov bx, offset data ; start from clock-wise half-step.
mov si, 0
mov cx, 0 ; step counter

next_step:
; motor sets top bit when it's ready to accept new command
wait:   in al, 7     
    test al, 10000000b
    jz wait

mov al, [bx][si]
out 7, al

inc si

cmp si, 4
jb next_step
mov si, 0

inc cx
cmp cx, steps_before_direction_change
jb  next_step

ret
endm  



r1 macro data 

; this is an example of out instruction.
; it writes values to virtual i/o port
; that controls the stepper-motor.
; c:\emu8086\devices\stepper_motor.exe is on port 7     

    steps_before_direction_change1 = 8h

    ;#start=stepper_motor.exe#

;#make_bin#
; 32 (decimal)

jmp start1


start1:
mov bx, offset data ; start from clock-wise half-step.
mov si, 0
mov cx, 0 ; step counter

next_step1:
; motor sets top bit when it's ready to accept new command
wait1:   in al, 7     
    test al, 10000000b
    jz wait1

mov al, [bx][si]
out 7, al

inc si

cmp si, 4
jb next_step1
mov si, 0

   inc cx
   cmp cx, steps_before_direction_change1
   jb  next_step1

   ret
   endm






s:mov ah,01h
int 21h

cmp al,'1' 
je l1  
jne l11

l11:cmp al,'2'
je l2 
jne l12

l12:jmp s  





l1:call init
SUB AX,AX  
mov ax,c
inc ax
mov c,ax
out 199, ax  
r datcw


l2:call init
SUB AX,AX  
mov ax,c
dec ax
mov c,ax
out 199, ax  
r1 datccw

jmp s  



datccw   db 0000_0011b
         db 0000_0001b    
         db 0000_0110b
         db 0000_0010b


datcw    db 0000_0110b
         db 0000_0100b    
         db 0000_0011b
         db 0000_0010b








init proc    
#start=led_display.exe#
#make_bin#
name led 
#start=stepper_motor.exe# 
#make_bin# 
name "stepper"   
ret
init endp


>
```

But when I enter 1 then 2 it caught in the loop and when I enter 1 then 1 it dose not work properly.

Please guide me how can I handle it?

Comment: Labels names like `l1`, `l2` and `s` are a terrible idea. It would be much better to pick names that actually have some relation to the labels' purposes.

Comment: please run my program perhaps u could sovle my problem tnx a lot